Trying to decipher CMake errors while building LLVM in Windows Docker Container
I'm trying to bootstrap LLVM 16 on Windows Docker Container for my CI needs using CMake and Ninja. The first stage of building clang and its associated tools with the system compiler (The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30154.0) works successfully. However, when I try to build LLVM with the built clang-cl.exe, I receive the following error:
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The ASM compiler identification is unknown
-- Found assembler: C:/workdir/llvm-stage-1/bin/clang-cl.exe
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/workdir/llvm-stage-1/bin/clang-cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/workdir/llvm-stage-1/bin/clang-cl.exe - broken
   CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
   The C compiler

    "C:/workdir/llvm-stage-1/bin/clang-cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/workdir/llvm-stage-2-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-zn73n4
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

    Run Build Command(s): C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ninja.exe -v cmTC_12e6d

    CreateProcess failed. Command attempted:
    "C:\workdir\llvm-stage-1\bin\clang-cl.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_12e6d.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c C:\workdir\llvm-stage-2-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-zn73n4\testCCompiler.c"
    ninja: fatal: CreateProcess: The system cannot find the path specified.

I am puzzled by this error log. What happened? Did CMake fail to recognize the compiler it just built? Do I not have the correct permissions to change directories? Did Ninja fail to create the process? How can I figure out what went wrong?
I mostly tried to update all dependencies in my Windows Container (ninja, cmake and Windows VS workloads).
Here's your text with corrected grammar:
UPD1: Paths to the compilers exist; I checked them manually and since I don't trust myself, I added checks using os.path.isfile() to my Python build script, which confirms that all paths exist.

"What happened?" - Ninja calls CreateProcess with the string specified under "Command attempted". This call returns error code which means "The system cannot find the path specified". Most likely the reason is that the executable file (C:\workdir\llvm-stage-1\bin\clang-cl.exe) doesn't exist.

This was my first guess too! But the C:\workdir\llvm-stage-1\bin\clang-cl.exe exists, it's a symlink to clang.exe.
